# CMake /w Ninja generates build files but no executable

Tags: c++, cmake, ninja

My first time attempt at CMake and I need some help

CMake /w Ninja & clang++ generates build files but no executable

/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)

project(Example)

include(find_compiler)

add_subdirectory(src)
```

src/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_executable(Example main.cpp)
```

I'm not sure what to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The primary purpose fo `CMake` is to create all the build-related files needed to create your executable (i.e. to configure build system), not to build it, so the behaviour you are experiencing is expected.

(I suppose you used Ninja generator, i.e. you executed cmake with `-G Ninja` as one of the parameters)

In order to actually build your executable, you must execute `ninja`, after successful configuration (i.e. successful run of `cmake`):

```
$ cd build_folder
$ cmake -G Ninja source_folder
$ ninja
```

if everything goes well,  you should have `Example` executable in you build folder.

You can also initiate actual building using CMake using following set fo commands:

```
$ cd build_folder
$ cmake -G Ninja source_folder
$ cmake --build .
```

cheers,

Comment: It looks like I was missing --build,  oops Thank you